# How can I create a report for "trending pages" in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to generate a report that shows which pages are getting visitors faster today/this month/etc.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you mean, and what past experience you have. I am assuming that you have some kind of programing experience. If you don't please update your question so that I can answer it better.

If you are asking about getting the data, you could try the [Google Analytics Core Reporting Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

If you are asking about formatting data you have:

First, get the data in a csv format. If you use Python (or are willing to learn), you could then use the [python csv api](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to use that data. You can then use python to turn that list into a pretty format.